# Simple join between two tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-grape

I am building a rails application to work as a back end for APIs. (using grape APIs)
I have two tables (user, comment) where a user has many comments and a comment belongs to one users.

I am trying to return all comments, and within the Comment object, i want to show the User object for the user who created that comment.

I tried:

```
Comment.includes(:user)
```

and

```
Comment.joins(:user).includes(:user)
```

And none of them managed to return the sub-object. only returns the Comment object (which has user_id) attribute).

Is there any way to achieve that in a JSON format (as mentioned, I use GRAPE)

Comment: Are you trying to find the `user` that "owns" each comment?

Comment: Yes. However, I want to return both as one object. Like: {comment.id: 1, comment.text: whatever, comment.user: {user.id: 1, user.firstname: john.......}}

Comment: Can you post the model relationships for User and Comment?

Comment: user has many comments, comment belongs to user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use to to_json or as_json with :include option. In your api:

```
resources :comments
  get :id do
    Comment.includes(:user).find(params[:id]).to_json(include: :user)
  end
end
```

However, sooner or later you will probably need more control over the json responses generated by your API. I would suggest you to take a look at [grape-rabl gem](https://github.com/LTe/grape-rabl) (or some other solution for building json - there are plenty of them out there). It will grant you much finer control...

Comment: I know I accepted this answer a long time ago; actually over 3 years ago. but would like to thank you again for it :)

Comment: I hope you're wearing a cape cause you're my hero

Answer (score 2):

if your Comment belongs_to User and your User has many comments

you can use this query:

```
Comment.find(:all, :joins => :user)
```

Answer (score 0):

User.all.select('*').joins(:comments)
The select method is needed to return all fields. I'd also get in practice of starting with parent table.